# How to solve 404 errror on page manualy created on wordpress theme folder?

Tags: wordpress, url, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a wordpress project, I use a wordpress theme and i need to add my custom page to that theme. When i created file in theme folder and open it on browser, wordpress show 404 error. I think wordpress cant find my page. im confused

Answer (score 0):

How you want to open your directory on your browser? like `example.com/directory` or `example.com/wp-content/themes/theme-name/directory` ?!

if you want `example.com/directory` you have to create your directory in your wordpress's root installation.